# What can we say about generating subsets if all free subsets are finite

Tags: universal-algebra

## Definitions

An (*universal*) *algebra* is a pair $\mathcal A=(A, (f_1,\dots, f_n))$ where $A$ is a non-empty set and $(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ is a family of finitary operations on $A$. The notation $o(f_i)$ will be used for the arity of $f_i$.

Given a subset $X$ of $\mathcal A$, the subalgebra of $\mathcal A$ generated by $X$, $\langle X\rangle$, is the smallest superset of $X$ stable by all $f_i$ functions. A subset $X$ is called *generating* iff $\langle X \rangle=A$.

A map $h:A\to B$ is called a *homomorphism* between $\mathcal A=(A, (f_1,\dots, f_n))$ and $\mathcal B=(B, (g_1,\dots, g_n))$ iff for all $i$ and $a_1,\dots, a_{o(f_i)} \in A$, $h(f_i(a_1,\dots, a_{o(f_i)}))=g_i(h(a_1),\dots, h(a_{o(f_i)}))$. A subset $X$ of $\mathcal A$ is called *free* if any function with domain $X$ can be extended to a homomorphism. (Obviously, we only consider functions that have an algebra with the same signature as codomain)

---

## Question

What can be said about generating subsets when all free subsets are finite?

(It'd be really awesome if it implied the existence of a finite generating subset)

Comment: The only restriction on the codomain of such an extension is that it has the same signature?

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of free subset can be reworded. Note that if $X\subseteq A$
is  free, then there is a homomorphism $h\colon A\to F(X)$
where $F(X)$ is the absolutely free algebra over $X$ in this
signature and $h$ is the identity on $X$. Conversely, if there is such a
homomorphism, then it is easy to check that $X$ is a free
subset.

Note also that
if such $h$ exists, then the freeness of $F(X)$ guarantees the existence
of a homomorphism $k\colon F(X)\to A$ that is the identity on $X$.
One can show that

(i) the map $e = kh$ is a retraction of $A$ onto the subalgebra
of $A$ generated by $X$, and

(ii) this subalgebra $\langle X\rangle$ is isomorphic to
$F(X)$; i.e. it is absolutely free over $X$.

Conversely it is not too hard to prove that if $A$ has a retraction
onto the subalgebra $\langle X\rangle$ and this subalgebra is absolutely
free over $X$, then $X$ is a free subset.

It might be easier to spot free subsets now, and to see how rare they are.
For example, if $X$ is a free subset of $A$, then $A$ can satisfy no
nontrivial identity in $|X|$ or fewer variables, since it has a subalgebra
$\langle X\rangle$ that satisfies no such identity.

This shows that, for example, no group, ring, module,
or Boolean algebra has any free subsets at all. Not even the empty
subset is free. [For groups, the identity $1\cdot 1 = 1$ holds,
and involves zero variables, so no subset of a group
containing zero or more elements can be free.] No nonempty subset of a semigroup or lattice can be free, since
these algebras satisfy nontrivial 1-variable identities. [E.g.
$x(xx)=(xx)x$, $x\wedge (x\wedge x)=(x\wedge x)\wedge x$ respectively.]

Thus, assuming that all free subsets are finite is often
a vacuous assumption.

To get back to the question you asked, having all free subsets finite does not imply the existence of a finite generating subset. For a counterexample, any uncountable group will not have any free subsets nor any finite generating subsets.